# Bottle cap with threads

Tags: modeling

Im wondering how I can extrude the faces outward and smooth them out so its rounded like a bottle cap. (This is suppose to be the inside of the bottle cap).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put it into a bit larger cylinder.

Tools used:
*Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*
*Vertex > New Face*, <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the Solidify modifier.  For this it's important to have your normals facing inside your bottle cap, so the effect pushes out.  Check your thickness to make sure the outside grooves of your screw threads aren't collapsing on themselves, and turn Even Thickness on and off to see which works better for you.  Then apply the modifier.

[image]