how can i clean up this geometry?
does anyone struggle with removing Ngons and Tris ?? for example after using knife or boolean, they feel like a different case exercise each time, i'd appreciate a course/tuto if anyone knows any.
there are cases where i can fully work with quads, but for a case like this for example

in that example, having made two spiral loopcuts, i end up with this :

how can i clean that up, and more importantly what's the thought process to address every knife/boolean related clean up situation.
i watched some tutorials but i somehow struggle to get keypoints about tackling this issue, bc with each tutorial the problem is different.
so i'd be grateful for a tuto that explains the thought process behind cleaning up.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather than point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248347/bottle-cap-with-threads https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190059/converting-bottle-threads-from-diagram-to-a-3d-model https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119230/bottle-thread-answer-doubt https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114765/how-to-model-spiral/114771#114771 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111834/how-to-model-this-particular-screw/111840#111840

This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

i honestly haven't researched in this platform, but i searched in yt..
and each time it's a different case, so i couldn't figure out keypoints and like.. algorithmic steps on how to think about removing tris and quads.
and maybe i haven't searched enough...
anw i edited the post for specifics..
thanks for the reply

What exactly is the issue here? It is a common misconception that you always have to make everything quads, so to answer your first question at the beginning: No, I usually do not struggle with removing ngons or tris, because most of the time I could not care less... what I want to say: if the existing topology creates no issues, leave it like that. But I'll try and give an answer how you could resolve the problem shown in the question.

Select the Knife Topology Tool with Alt+K (Blender 4.2) or K (Blender 4.1 and older versions) and left-click on the mesh to cut from one of the vertices on the left of the ngon to one corner vertex to the right (a green square indicates you're snapping to the vertex) with a click inbetween.

Then right-click to set a new cut, and do the same for the lower part.

Then right-click again, now connect the two cut points in the middle.

Then hit Return to confirm the cuts and that's it, now you have only quads.

